# How to change dynamically the text value of an <a-text>?

Tags: aframe

I want to make a dynamic digital clock in [A-Frame](https://aframe.io/). I'm using a text element but I can't change its text by setting the property in JS. I can still change others attributes like the color.

#### html:

```
...
<a-text id="clock" clock-text value="00:00" position="2.45 0 0.01" color="#FFFFFF" align="right"></a-text>
...
```

#### js:

```
...
AFRAME.registerComponent('clock-text', {
  init: function() {
    var el = this.el;
    el.setAttribute('value', '20:30');
    el.setAttribute('color', 'black');
  },
  update: function() {
    el.setAttribute('value', '20:30');
  }
});
```

You can get the full code in [the jsfiddle I'm using](https://jsfiddle.net/crazyrems/cp1y47kr/).

Comment: The code works now, and it was a typo issue…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think this is a race condition issue, since there's actually two updates going on in `a-text`, when it initializes and when it receives the new value (causing a component `update` to be called).

the text component does emit one event called ['textfontset' when `updateFont` gets called from its `init`](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/cfbd4825f7104147993dab99f8d4ec60d39d3d7b/src/components/text.js#L228).

Using that event, you can start your clock after that event is emitted

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('clock-text', {
  init: function() {
    var el = this.el;
    this.ready = false;
      el.addEventListener('textfontset', function() {
      this.ready = true;
    }.bind(this));
  },
  tick: function() {
    var el = this.el;
    if (!this.ready) {
      return;
    }
    el.setAttribute('value', '20:30');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xcofjjm9/1/

Comment: this was what I was looking for `el.setAttribute('value', '20:30')` I was just doing el.value="20:30" - thank you :-)